# Simple Ruby Editor?

Tags: ruby, windows, linux, editor

This editor isn't intended for me.  It's intended for teaching someone else Ruby.  I largely use Emacs when writing Ruby.  Does anyone know of an editor that

1. indents the current line correctly when you press tab,
2. can indent the whole file correctly (keyboard shortcut would be nice),
3. has syntax highlighting for Ruby,
4. other than that works kind of like Windows Notepad (maybe with a toolbar of icons),
5. has a built in terminal (not absolutely required),
6. has multiple editor tabs,
7. and works on Windows, Linux, or both?

Or anything somewhat close?

Edit:
I'm also going to add that I'd like to be available for free (legally for an indefinite period of time).  Open source wouldn't hurt.

Comment: What's wrong with emacs?

Comment: [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-2-beta)

Comment: @Yasouser -- would you like a list?  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Check [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)

[image]

Comment: AFAIK Notepad++ doesn't indent the current line like Emacs if you press Tab.

Comment: it's indentation is fully configurable. Also it's logo is __super awesome__ (I've added a pic so everyone can see)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/) has a built-in terminal, but I believe it does everything else you need.  It's implemented in Java, so it should run on any platform for which a JVM exists, including Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not a die hard fan of emacs, then there's always vim and its plugins for any programming language. Here's one for Ruby: [rails.vim : Ruby on Rails: easy file navigation, enhanced syntax highlighting, and more](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1567)

If you are new to vim, this cheat sheet should help you: [vim graphical cheat sheet](http://www.glump.net/_media/howto/vi-vim-cheat-sheet-and-tutorial.pdf)

Comment: if he's trying to teach someone `ruby`, he probably doesn't want to spend a month teaching `vim`

Comment: In my opinion, learning how to use vim is worth the time. It will definitely save you a lot of time during coding. I started late, but now I feel why I didn't spend the time long back.

Comment: Seriously, the investment is totally worth it!

Comment: The investment is worth it, but will distract the Ruby newbie from learning Ruby -- which is even more worth it...

Answer (score 2):

Since it's about teaching ruby [RedCar](http://redcareditor.com) and [Diakonos](http://diakonos.pist0s.ca) are good choices. They have most of the features you mention and as a bonus both are written in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

I like gedit - it doesn't have a terminal, but should work fine for the other requirements.  It can run on Windows with Cygwin.

For a full-blown IDE, Aptana Studio is great.  It meets your requirements.

Comment: Is there a way to have it indent as I described?

Comment: It runs on Windows w/o Cygwin as well.

Comment: Yes - in the preferences, you can enable automatic indentation.

Comment: Rafe Kettler - I didn't know that! I'll need to check it out - thanks.

Comment: @Brian Knight: Does it automatically indent a line to the correct position when you press tab?

Comment: Yes - you can set the tab size default as well.

Answer (score 0):

If your main goal is to teach then you could try using Hackety Hack. It is somewhat weak at times, but I found it fun and simple to use, but then again I already knew ruby pretty well.

For a beginner being able to run the programs easily is very important so you want something where irb and ruby can be run very simply. Aptana seems to be a pretty good IDE for this sort of thing, but I have never used it myself aside for web development.

Aside from those two I suggest Notepad++... Also the free [KomodoEdit](http://www.activestate.com/komodo-edit) might be worth a look. Personally I say teach the other person emacs, but then again *shrug*

Comment: I tend to agree, but it depends on the situation.